# Linking the Developer Page at the appStore from an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, url, app-store, itunes

So I know how to open an app page on the appStore from within my iPhone app.

Is there a way to open my company's page? On iTunes on my mac I can do that, but using that URL in the iPhone I can't (or I'm not doing it right).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great article on this subject:  http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/

> **Quote from the article:**

http://itunes.com/apps/developer — Search for all apps by developer

It’s also possible to link to all apps by one developer, but there’s a catch. On a Mac or a PC,
this will open iTunes and land on a developer’s page. On an iPhone or iPod touch it’ll do a bit of a
dance, opening MobileSafari, then iTunes, then the App Store app. Not ideal, a bit ugly and slow, but
it gets there in the end.

If you’d like to hide the redirections and speed up the process, Apple recommend using `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since I am passing the link in the html body of a mail message sent from my app, I can't do "the dance", but if it is not too slow, that's a way to go. I'll try it now.

Comment: Actually after trying it, it doesn't seem to work. For instance, for the creators of Angry Birds I used http://itunes.com/apps/clickgamer.com and it doesn't take me anywhere.

Comment: Just another comment to state here, humbly, for the whole world to read, that I am a very very dumb man. I was doing it wrong. It works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: The only way we all learn is from making mistakes :)  Glad you worked it out

Answer (score 6):

this prevents it to do little dance it does normally

```
 NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/companyname/";
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Answer (score 2):

I used such URL in iOS 8, 9:

`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/developer/tivogi/id507966848`

where `tivogi` is the developer's account name and `id507966848` is the your developer id.

You can find correct link for you in the any browser: just go to developer page, copy url, and change scheme to `itms-apps`

Comment: Where can I find my developer id?

Answer (score 0):

In IOS SDK 6 and above, use below link for open developer link from app

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewArtist?artistId=524402507"]];

........